# Pattern matching with maps in F#

Tags: f#

Given the map:

```
let myMap = Map.ofArray [| (1,"A");(2,"B") |]
```

Is there a way i can use pattern matching similiar to a list cons operator?

Something like this:

```
match myMap with      //doesn't work
    (1, value) -> ()
  | _          -> ()
```

Or:

```
match myMap with      //doesn't work 
    1::value -> ()
  | _        -> ()
```

What i don't want to do is this:

```
match myMap.TryFind(1) with      //boring
    Some value -> ()
  | _          -> ()
```

How can I do pattern matching with a map?

Comment: Author an ActivePattern that calls TryFind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you noted, matching over `TryFind` is the standard approach and I can't think of a compelling reason to wrap it with an active pattern for a simple key check. However, if you're going for something like list destructuring (i.e. return the found value and the remainder of the map) this should work:

```ml
let (|Found|_|) key map =
  map
  |> Map.tryFind key
  |> Option.map (fun x -> x, Map.remove key map)

let map = Map.ofList [1, "A"; 2, "B"]
match map with
| Found 1 (x, rest) -> printfn "Value: %A, Remaining: %A" x rest
| _ -> ()

//prints: Value: "A", Remaining: map [(2, "B")]
```

Comment: Paul, I think your cat hit the keyboard.

Comment: My cat is nowhere _near_ that precise.